# Define custom actions for Outlook "Quick Steps" in an add-in

Tags: c#, office-interop, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I would like to create a custom "Quick Steps" action for an Outlook 2010 Add-In.  Quick Steps seems like a perfect structure for what I'm trying to accomplish:  I need to take an action based on the currently selected items.  The action requires a destination folder.

I'd love to be able to extend Quick Steps with a custom Action, something like this:

[image: Select custom action]

[image: Select folder for custom action]

How do I hook into Quick Steps to add a custom action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this thread at msdn forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ta/outlookdev/thread/9ce35f49-56aa-493f-bb6e-7dc2daf12516), it's not possible.

I'd love for that link to be proven wrong, if anyone knows a way to add a custom quick step action.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27827/create-and-customize-quick-steps-in-outlook-2010/
http://ophir.wordpress.com/2010/06/13/outlook-2010-quick-steps-are-cool/

Found them using this search:

https://www.google.com/search?q=outlook+2010+macro+quick+steps&aq=f&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Those tutorials show how to define your own quick steps. I already know how to do that. What I want to do is to create a custom action that can be selected by the user when defining a new quick step.